# Why Subsection at top-bar in fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textsc{Department}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

% \section{Objective Data} % nothing at left top when this active

\subsection{Status localis}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Expected output: without *0.1 Status localis* at the top-left bar.

---

How can you have no subsection at top-left bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just say `\lhead{}`, i.e. an empty left page heading, because this is used by `\leftmark{}` normally, which prints a section etc. title.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\textsc{Department}}
\lhead{}%
\cfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

%\section{Objective Data} % nothing at left top when this active

\subsection{Status localis}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be better to issue `\fancyhf{}` to clear all fields, before filling them up.

Comment: @egreg: True,but in `fancy` style most of the fields aren't occupied right from start, so it's only `\lhead` left to be filled/changed. (I am speaking of a 'virgin' fancy style, not something that has been changed already)

Comment: It depends on the class used, I guess.

Comment: @egreg: I'll take a look into `fancyhdr` whether there is a `class`-switch or a specific setting for `ps@myheading` etc.